# Call all of extjs store listeners instace with an event

Tags: extjs, store

I have an store and use it some place. This class store have 'datachanged' event and I want to each of them(instances) do own work. How can I do this?

updated:

myStore: calk

```
Ext.define('FM.store.Calk', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'FM.model.Calk',
    autoLoad: true,
    config: {

    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        //url: 'calk/read/',
        api:{
            read: 'calk/read/',
            update: 'calk/update/'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'calks'
        }
    },
    sorters: [{
        property: 'text',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }],
    listeners: {},

    initComponent: function()
    {
        var me = this;

        Ext.apply(me, {});

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

view: i use one of Store here

```
Ext.define('FM.view.tree.Panel', {
    // Ext.panel.Panel-specific options:
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.mmTreePanel',
    requires: [],
    title: "لایه ها",
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    border: true,
    collapsible: true,
    collapseMode: "mini",
    autoScroll: true,
    rootVisible: false,
    lines: false,

    initComponent: function()
    {
        var me = this;
        var dataNodeChanged = function(e, ee, eee){
            console.log("its fine");

        };

        calkStore = Ext.create('FM.store.Calk',{});

        calkStore.on({"load": dataNodeChanged, this);
        calkStore.on({"datachanged": dataNodeChanged, this);

        var tbar = {
            xtype:  'mmTreeTbar'
        };

        Ext.apply(me, {
            tbar: tbar,
            root: {
                expanded: true,
                children: []
            }
            //displayField: 'name'
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

My app: i use one of store here

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'FM',
    appFolder: 'app',
    controllers: ['Main'],
    models: ['Calk'],
    stores: ['Calk'],
    autoCreateViewport: true,

    launch: function(){

        var dataNodeChanged = function(){
            console.log("Application Instanse");
        };

        cs = Ext.create('FM.store.Calk',{});


        cs.on({"load": function(){console.log("App Load")}}, this);
        cs.on({"datachanged": function(){console.log("App DataChanged")}}, this);
    }
});
```

now in chrom console i run `cs.reload()` or `calkStore.reload()`

Comment: Are you asking how to handle this event correctly?

Comment: not very clear can you improve your question please even describing what you tried so far ?

Comment: You should not be using Ext.create('FM.store.Calk',{}); within the launch function. The store will get created for you automatically. You should configure your store with a storeId, then in your launch function use Ext.getStore('myStoreId') to get the reference to your store. You are effectively creating multiple instances of the same store otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You should just add a listener for the datachanged event for both stores and then in the listener handler code just call your custom functions.

```
store1.on({'datachanged': function(this, options) {
      store1DataChange();
},this);
```

Comment: Can you update your code so I can see exactly what you are doing?

Comment: addLestener should be addListener. Also how are you adding and updating records in the store?

Comment: Ok but how are you modifying records in your code? The datachanged event will only fire if records have been added or updated in some way, so you must have code somewhere that's doing this part?

Comment: My records modify in server and I reload store.

Comment: Are you using load() or reload() on the store?

Comment: I'm using reload() method.

Comment: In my first load, execute both of them, but in second use, only one of them    execute

Comment: See my second answer, in the docs it tells you what events fire on the load and reload method calls.

Answer (score 0):

The store reload method will not fire the datachanged event, see here http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-reload

Instead you should listen to the load event.

**EDIT**

Instead of the addListener approach, try listening for the events this way:

```
store1.on("datachanged", store1DataChange, this);
store1.on("load", store1Load, this);
```

Also, are you sure when you are calling reload() that a server request is being made and if yes, are you certain that there is newer data coming back? If nothing changes then the datachanged event wont fire.

Comment: if I use store1.reload(), execute store1DataChange() and if I use store2.reload(), execute store2DataChange(.

Comment: Are you using the same parameters for loading\reloading the stores each time, or will these change? Can you update your code showing how your proxy works? Also, see my latest edit in my answer about using the .on() approach

Comment: I change my code according to you, and reload() response is differs with first response.Because of I added 2 event, only store1DataChange() execture twice.

Comment: Can you post your full code so I can see what you are doing now please